# Identificador único dispositivo android

Tags: android

Tenho o seguinte problema na minha aplicação. Na primeira inicialização eu capturo o androidID utilizando o seguinte método:

```
 Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)
```

Este código está sendo utlizada para validar em um webservice se é a primeira instalação do aplicativo em determinado dispositivo.

Porém ao realizar uma atualização do sistema android, ou dar um recovery no mesmo esse código é gerado novamente, a documentação do Google diz que ele é atualizado sempre que é feito a primeira inicialização do sistema.

Preciso de um código que seja único e não pode ser o IMEI pois ele não existe em dispositivos que não possuem chip.

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Não consigo visualizar completamente o seu problema, mas não poderia ser um cadastro onde o usuário informe o e-mail? Esse e-mail é único em seu cadastro.

Comment: Opa, não posso usar o e-mail pois o dipositivo pode ser usado por vários usuário, e por isso travo com usuário e senha. Preciso de um ID pois o sistema é cobrado por cópias, no momento do primeiro cadastro eu pego uma série de dados do dispositivo e envio para o webService e até então achava que o AndroidID era único e imutável, porém hoje descobri que ele muda, com isso o dispositivo é cadastrado novamente e diminui no número de cópias do usuário.

Comment: Já deu uma olhada aqui? Muitas informações.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id

Comment: Já tinha dado uma olhada e vou olhar novamente. Valeu.

Comment: Não pode ser o ID registrado pelo GCM / FCM?

Comment: Resolvi utilizando MACADRESS da placa de rede. Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, ID único no Android é um pouco complicado de se ter com certeza, existem diversos lugares que fornecem um ID e nem sempre o mesmo lugar está disponível em todos os dispositivos, minha solução foi criar um ID próprio combinando todas as informações que posso conseguir.

Utilizo isso pra controlar o acesso e sinceramente nunca tive problema de mudar (porém, pode ser que mude se o celular for formatado ou trocar de sim), então, acredito que seja ideal no primeiro acesso gravar esse ID em um banco no celular (que não mudaria caso mudasse o SIM), neste caso, só perderia o ID se formatasse o celular, o que também acionaria uma primeira instalação.

Segue o código que utilizo:

```
 final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    final String tmDevice, tmSerial, androidId;
    tmDevice = "" + tm.getDeviceId();
    tmSerial = "" + tm.getSimSerialNumber();
    androidId = "" + android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(androidId.hashCode(), ((long) tmDevice.hashCode() << 32) | tmSerial.hashCode());
    String deviceId = deviceUuid.toString();
```

Esse código gerará um ID neste formato: `00000000-5ff5-17e8-ffff-ffff9d6a7f8f`

Comment: Resolvi utilizando MACADRESS da placa de rede. Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Se a resposta te ajudou, ou você achou pertinente a questão, por favor marque-a como resposta :)

Answer (score 1):

A classe Build tem alguns identificadores que podem ajudar.

Essa classe traz informações sobre a compilação atual, extraídas das propriedades do sistema.

Exemplo de informações de compilação tiradas de um dispositivo:

```
Build.ID: QQ1D.200105.002

Build.USER: genymotion

Build.VERSION.RELEASE: 10

Build.Time: 1591957173000

Build.Host: 8cb93f10a5dd

Build.Hardware: vbox86
```

Exemplo em código:

```
String id = Build.ID + Build.USER + Build.VERSION.RELEASE + Build.TIME + Build.HOST + Build.HARDWARE;
System.out.println(id);
//output: QQ1D.200105.002genymotion1015919571730008cb93f10a5ddvbox86
```

Existem outras variáveis na classe Build que eu não disse aqui, caso você queira saber mais:[Build Class(Android OS)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.os.build?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9)

Juntar informações da classe de construção pode gerar um identificador exclusivo para você.